# C++ IDE for STL containers

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, stl, containers

What C++ IDE natively support STL containers view in debug mode?

One IDE is Visual Studio, but I'm looking to move from it and would like to have STL containers in debug mode. Specifically looking now for Windows IDEs, other OS IDEs welcome.

Comment: Depends on the compiler and debugger you use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse!

"CDT debug now supports full pretty-printing of STL structures using GDB 7.0 or later. This means that complex structures such as Maps, Lists and Vectors, will be shown in a user-friendly fashion." ([source](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_can_I_inspect_the_contents_of_STL_containers.3F))

(CDT is Eclipse's C/C++ Development Tooling)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Visual Studio supports the ability to write custom debug inspector scripts for exactly this situation. You can write a script that tells the debugger exactly how to evaluate and display the STL containers (or any other complex type) you want to view.

Recent versions of Embarcadero C++Builder (and Delphi) also now support the ability to write custom inspectors for complex types, using compiled code instead of scripts.